# Shopify Plus - How to replace city dropdown with city text field with Checkout UI Extention

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

Shopify is going to deprecate checkout.liquid it is no longer available to use. Shopify wants us to migrate or build apps to customize the checkout using Checkout UI Extention.

I have already created the extension and created the city dropdown.

I am building this app for **Shopify Plus** store.

**Question 1**: How to replace my custom city dropdown with the Shopify default city field?
**Question 2**: How to apply custom CSS to the whole checkout.

[image]

Please give me some suggestions and references that help me to get this done.